# "nodemon --exec yarn lint && yarn start" runs only yarn lint

Tags: yarnpkg, nodemon

- `nodemon -v`: 1.14.10
- `node -v`: 9.2.0
- Operating system/terminal environment: Windows 10, git CMD

`"nodemon --exec yarn lint && yarn start"` doesn't work properly. runs only first command `yarn lint`
[image]
As I understand, it should say: `[nodemon] starting yarn lint && yarn start`
if to do in the following way: `"nodemon --exec 'yarn lint && yarn start'"` - it doesn't work at all.
The error message is 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
PATHs are defined.
the project structure is the following:
[image]

package.json file:

[image]

The issue with more details and project itself can be found here:
https://github.com/IvaTsu/summary/issues/1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that this will work `"dev": "nodemon --exec \"yarn lint && yarn start\"`